# How to initialize array or object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I don't know how to initialize an object or array like this:

```
contacts:

- messages:
-- 'Hello, man'
-- 'What is going on'
-- 'idk i will call you later'

- usernames:
-- 'Antonio Capuccino'
-- 'Karlo Frunze'
-- 'Punisher3000'
```

And that is how I want to find this data:

- Input: `contacts.messages[0]`
- Output: `'Hello, man'`

Or:

- Input: `contacts.usernames[2]`
- Output: `'Punisher3000'`

Comment: You can just google it. You can find like million videos or samples out there

Comment: @YousafRaza But what had I to type? I don't know how defenetly it calls.

Comment: Initially, you can type whatever you think it should be like "declare array inside object". You will get the hang of it with time. Just google whatever you think it is. I guarantee you will get the answer. I would suggest that you take a JS crash course if you are having difficulty with syntax. You can find it free on youtube

Comment: @YousafRaza Wow, so much usefull information. Thank you for suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object like this

```js
const contacts = {
  messages: [
    "Hello, man",
    "What is going on",
    "idk i will call you later",
  ],
  usernames: [
    "Antonio Capuccino",
    "Karlo Frunze",
    "Punisher3000",
  ],
};

console.log(contacts.messages[0]);
console.log(contacts.usernames[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
const contacts = {
  messages: ["Hello, man", "What is going on", "idk i will call you later"],
  usernames: ["Antonio Capuccino", "Karlo Frunze", "Punisher3000"],
};

console.log("Example One: " + contacts.messages[0])
console.log("Example Two: " + contacts.usernames[2])
```